# Let $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$, with $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{6}(3xy^2-4x^2y+y^3+10)$. Find the equation at the tangent plan of f at the point $(3,2)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I've answered this question and I got:

$f_x(a,b)=-6$

$f_y(a,b)=2$

$f(a,b)=-3$

and my answer is: $-6x+2y+9$

Just wanted to know whether I am on the right tracks here?

The second part to this question then asks us to find the directional derivative of $f$ at point $(3,2)$ in the direction of vector $u=\binom{-4}3$

I got $6$ for this answer.

Thanks for your help,

Struggling Statistics Student.

Comment: Do you know the equation of the tangent plane in general?

Comment: Yeah $x-a*f_x(a,b)+y-b*f_y(a,b)+z-f(a,b)*-1$ ?

Comment: That's not an equation, you're missing $=0$ at the end. Does your proposed answer look like what's in your comment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is almost right but I don't know where the 9 came from.

The tangent plane at point $(x_0 = 3, y_0 = 2)$  at $(x_0,y_0)$ will be  the map
$$
\bar{f}(x,y) = f_x (x - x_0) + f_y (y- y_0) + f(x_0,y_0)
$$
which comes out to 
$$
\bar{f}(x,y) = -6 (x -3) + 2(y- 2) -3 = -6x + 2y + 11
$$

The directional derivative in direction $\hat{u}$ is $\hat{u}\cdot \nabla f$.  The direction given is not unit length so you have to divide by its length of $5$ to get:
$$
\frac{1}{5} (-4, 3) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} -6 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) = 6$$

Comment: Bloody hell when I wrote it down I mistook the z for a 2. Thanks!